# How to handle NestedNullException (extends RuntimeException)

Tags: java

I want to get a property via string like:

```
PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(object, propertyName);
```

For example I have Person object and I want to get the name of the father...

```
PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(person, "father.firstName");
```

Now maybe the person doesn't have a father so the object is null and I get a org.apache.commons.beanutils.NestedNullException.

Is it ok to catch this exception (since it is a runtime exception) or should I first find out if the father is null? Or are there other workarounds?

Comment: For a nested property, it is always good to validate whether the parent property fetched is null and then proceed to fetch the child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect a `null` return instead of `NestedNullException` if the nested property is null, you can create your own static method that wraps the `PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty` and catches `NestedNullException` to return `null`:

```
public static Object getNestedPropertyIfExists(Object bean, String name) {
    try {
        return PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(bean, name);
    } catch (NestedNullException e) {
      // Do nothing
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah apache should add this or add param _allowNull_ to the get property functions. Also problematic with _BeanComparator_ and _ComparableComparator_ all ignoring the facts that values can be _null_. We had to create our own classes for those cases.